# What is a good IR-receiver for my Linux (XBMC) HTPC?

Tags: linux, htpc, remote-control

I have bought a Asrock 330 ION-BD and use it as a HTPC.
I'm running XBMC under Linux (Ubuntu).

I'm missing a good Remote control. The problem is that 
the Asrock doesn't have an IR receiver onboard and I
can only extend on USB ports.

So, my question; **are there IR to USB recievers for Linux?**

Maybe a combined solution; a (universal) remote control with a IR to USB?

Answer (score 3):

[LIRC](http://www.lirc.org/) is the package that handles IR communication in linux, so you could pick up any IR to USB receivers listed in the [USB devices](http://www.lirc.org/html/table.html#@hw-usb) compatibility section. There is also a list of supported remote controls on the main page.

You could also ask the [XBMC community forum](http://www.xbmc.org/forum/showthread.php?p=379957) for suggestions from people who've already done this.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to buy a remote for a media center that comes with a reciever. Perhaps [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16880121003)? Check out other products in the category and then start searching to make sure the IR Reciever works in linux. Most of them probably will.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are.

I use a Microsoft Windows Media Center OEM remote with my homebuilt Mythtv PC (bought from Newegg). The remote came with a receiver that works just fine in Linux.

The list in Nagul's link  has a whole bunch of them, but I figure a specific data point can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but be aware that Linux almost exclusively supports IR remotes.

If the pc is in front of you anyway (next to a TV) then it may not be an issue.
If the pc is behind you (under a projector) then you'd have to aim your IR remote *behind* you...

I have several RF remotes and haven't gotten any of them to work on Linux. (I'd have to write the drivers myself...)